# How to set Unique property to a field in laravel

Tags: laravel

I've a table of building in which there is building name in db.when i add building through blade if the building name exist then it can not added. instead of storing it to db i want to show some error.what should i do?

this is my validation

```
  $validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(),
        [
            'b_name' => 'required|max:20',
        ],
        [
            'b_name.required' => '*please fill this field',

        ]
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) {

        return Response::make([
            'message' => trans('validation_failed'),
            'errors' => $validator->errors(),
        ]);
      } 
      if ($validator->passes()) {
    $name = $request->input('b_name');
    $description = $request->input('b_description');
    $created_at = Carbon::now();
    $updated_at = Carbon::now();
    $array = array('name' => $name, 'description' => $description, 'created_at' => $created_at, 'updated_at' => $updated_at);
    Building::insert($array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                'b_name' => 'required|max:20|unique:buildings,name',
            ],
            [
                'b_name.required' => '*please fill this field',
                'b_name.unique' => ('*building name already exists'),

            ]
        );
        if ($validator->fails()) {

            return Response::make([
                'message' => trans('validation_failed'),
                'errors' => $validator->errors(),
            ]);
          } 
          if ($validator->passes()) {
        $name = $request->input('b_name');
        $description = $request->input('b_description');
        $created_at = Carbon::now();
        $updated_at = Carbon::now();
        $array = array('name' => $name, 'description' => $description, 'created_at' => $created_at, 'updated_at' => $updated_at);
        Building::insert($array);
return 1;
}
Response::json(['errors' => $validator->errors()]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If **b_name** is your input for building name and **name** is your database field name for **Building** model then try this code in your validation.

```
'b_name' => 'required|max:20|unique:App\Building,name'
```

For more details visit : https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-unique

Answer (score 0):

Your code shoulde be like

```
      $input = $request->all();
      $rules = ['b_name' => 'required|required|unique:table_name,b_name|max:20'];
      $messages = [
                   'b_name.required' => '*please fill this field'
                   'b_name.unique' => 'building name already taken.'
                  ];
      $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```